# Create react app didn't working with no errors just timeout

Tags: javascript, npx

Node version is v17.0.0[image] i tried many Node versions lts and more.... I've been waiting for a few minutes but it still not working my opinion is it is not a network problem Because i reseted my wifi router but it still not working.... and I reset my computer and reinstall nodejs and tried once again.. but not working! how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I see that your using **wsl environment on windows** try to change it to windows default environment. Last week i was also struggling with the same, i changed to default then it started working fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).